# How to zoom a chart in d3 correctly?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot, zooming

I am trying to add zoom to a linechart in d3.

```
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
   .x(xScale)
   .y(yScale)
   .scaleExtent([1, 10])
   .on("zoom", zoomed);
element.call(zoom);

function zoomed() {
   element.attr("transform", "scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
    .select(".x.d3-axis").attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')').call(xAxis)
     .select(".y.d3-axis").attr('transform', 'translate(0,0)').call(yAxis);
    };
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d6q7n5pw/2/)

However, each time the chart is zoomed, it moves to the left. I can't seem to find a way to bring it back to the original position when zoom action is done.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to translate your element, in addition to scaling it. Right now, your zoom function is *only* scaling `element`.

By changing the transform to include `d3.event.translate`, you will get the desired behavior.

```
function zoomed() {
  element
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")

  ...
}
```

Here is your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fvyug65k/) with the updated code.

---

### Update

To get rid of the strange offsets, just add your margin to the `d3.event.translate` values:

```
var translate = [d3.event.translate[0] + margin.left, d3.event.translate[1] + margin.top];

element
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")")
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a3tvmuor/)

In addition, if you want to make sure that the SVG only stays within the original borders (no overflow), you should check out the [SVG `clipPath` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking).

Comment: Thanks for your solution. However, the fiddle you posted doesn't solve this entirely. With every zoom-in zoom-out it shifts a little to the left. Is it because of the margin?